# Can't find setup project properties in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2005, setup-project

All of the various postings, when speaking of Setup projects in vs2005, simply say "the properties are there" and/or "In Studio, I just click on the project name in the Explorer and I get the property window typical to other projects, and it's right there."  BUT I DON'T!!  I get a very limited list of properties (Output file name, Package files (as):, Compression, and URL.  That's it!  You can't believe how frustrating this is!  I'm assuming it's something simply I'm (not) doing.  PLEASE HELP.  How do I get access to the miriad of Setup Properties???

Comment: Can you set this question as answered, please? The answer of John Sheehan was an excelent answer. I have the same problem and that answer save me.

Answer (score 6):

Highlight your project and hit F4. That's the properties pane. Right click and select Properties for the project properties dialog.

Answer (score 2):

The F4 key is mapped to display the Setup Properties pane if the keyboard is set up as C#.  If your default keyboard layout is C++, F4 does nothing.